# How to override rescue_from in application controller for one specific instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in my `application_controller.rb`:

```
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

def user_not_authorized
  redirect_back fallback_location: root_url,
                 warning: 'Not authorized'
end
```

but for one method, I need

```
def slug_available
  authorize Page
rescue Pundit::NotAuthorizedError
  render status: :unauthorized
else
  render json: { available: Page.where(slug: params[:slug]).empty? }
end
```

However, the `rescue_from` is overriding the explicit `rescue` in `slug_available`, and I am getting a 302 Found instead of a 401 Unauthorized.

I would have thought an explicit `rescue` would have taken priority. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that replacing

```
render status: :unauthorized
```

with

```
render plain: 'Not authorized.', status: :unauthorized
```

fixed the problem. It looks like Rails was trying to render the current page as HTML, with a 401 status, until I was explicit about *what* to render.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `not_authorized` declaration method in your controller and check the `action_name`.

```
protected

def not_authorized
  if action_name == 'slug_available'
    render status: :unauthorized
  else
    super
  end
end
```

then, you do not need to authorize your `slug_avaiable` action method

```
def slug_available
  render json: { available: Page.where(slug: params[:slug]).empty? }
end
```

The `ApplicationController` base method needs to be a protected method.